# how to render a grid as like table

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

Need to render a grid as like table format, for example i have two rows initially followed by below css:

**Step 1:**

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**output**:

[image]

I dynamically added one more column, but it render like below its correct only but i need row wise render the coloumn any tricky is there in css. please guide what is way to achieve.

i have one idea, that is based on order will render the grid like any other option to render,

**step 2:**

```
.grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**I expected like below:**

[image]

Comment: read about grid-auto-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `grid-auto-flow` to `column` and then change `grid-template-columns` to `grid-template-rows` (because you are filling the grid column-wise now).

In other words, try this in your CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

There's a JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/h8qm5sku/3/ in case that helps